# How to manage channel's playlists using YouTube Data API?

Tags: curl, youtube-api

I currently have a private Google (that includes YouTube) account with a YouTube channel. I want to create and generally manage playlists on channel account (instead of private account/channel). When I'm querying `POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists` I can only manage my private account.

I have tried this:

```bash
# Generated by Google Bard AI
curl -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_API_KEY]" \
  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
```

I can see only my private account main channel.

And this:

```bash
# From: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
curl --request POST \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet,status&onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel=[ChannelID]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"snippet":{"title":"Test 1","description":"Test playlist."},"status":{"privacyStatus":"unlisted"}' \
  --compressed
```

Returns:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Missing content owner id.",
        "domain": "youtube.api.v3.RequestContextError",
        "reason": "ERROR_CONTENT_OWNER_CHANNEL_WITHOUT_CONTENT_OWNER"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

When I apply my private account channel ID, it returns:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The authenticated user cannot act on behalf of the specified Google account.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The authenticated user cannot act on behalf of the specified Google account.",
        "domain": "youtube.common",
        "reason": "accountDelegationForbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As far as I understand, as long I'm not a YouTube Partner (which I'm not) I can't use it... Right?

Comment: You can use all [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/) and [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/) endpoints without being a YouTube partner.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison my problem wasn't about using endpoints generally. It was about using them on behalf of my channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']
)
credentials = flow.run_local_server()
youtube = build(
    'youtube',
    'v3',
    credentials=credentials
)

body = dict(
    snippet=dict(
        title='Test playlist',
        description='Playlist generated with YouTube API.'
    ),
    status=dict(
        privacyStatus='private'
    )
)

playlists_insert_response = youtube.playlists().insert(
    part='snippet, status',
    body=body
).execute()

playlist_id = playlists_insert_response.get('id')

print(f'New playlist ID: {playlist_id}.')
```

During verification process I've selected my channel to verify in app. Playlist has been created on that channel.